# Java Security API access in EJB module?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-security

I'm using Wildfly (the latest version) and I have 3 modules (2x .WAR and 1x EJB .JAR). I'm using Soteria (Java Security API) for the two wars. Their pom looks like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.soteria</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.security.enterprise</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

For each of the wars, I've defined their own AuthenticationMechanisms, IdentityStores and CallerPrincipals (UserPrincipal and EmployeePrincipal). The implementation is basically copied from the Soteria github. This all works fine when each of them is concerned separately.

The problem is, when I want to get the CallerPrincipal in the EJB module, I don't have access to the CallerPrincipals in the wars and the only way I can even access the Principals is via SessionContext, like this:

```
sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal();  // Has only .getName()
```

But I would like to use it like this:

```
(UserPrincipal) sessionContext.getCallerPrincipal(); // Has my entity as defined in UserPrincipal
```

When I try to move the CallerPrincipals to the EJB module I get this error:

```
Unsatisfied dependencies for type IdentityStore with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private 
com.trivia.api.security.authentication.ClientBasicAuthenticationMechanism.identityStore
```

I suspect it is because the IdentityStore can't find its CallerPrincipal.

Is this expected behaviour?